Does Google support app passwords as of today?
I read online that Google stopped support for app passwords and uses OAuth, so I want to confirm this?
I have a script that sends a form submission to my email and it stopped working.
If that's the case, I might need a pointer to how to solve this because I also read online that I need administrator Google account to use this OAuth, but it requires a domain at Google, which I don't have...

I would guess google is correct and the preconditions for your usecase are not met.
